# Compile selective part of my source tree using Ant

Tags: ant, compilation, target, javac, conditional-statements

My situation is somehow interesting. I am trying to use Ant to make a jar file. However, I don't want every single java file to be compiled. My source code has strcuture something like this:

```
src
-Contact.Java
-Contact.hbm.xml
-AnotherClass.Java
```

So, what I want to have in my jar file is as follow:

```
myjar.jar
-com
--me
---Contact.Class
---Contact.hbm.xml
```

I don't want AnotherClass.Class to be there.

Is it possible doint that with Ant ?

The best I come up with is like this:

```
<target name="condition-hibernate" description="check if there is a java and hbm file then call for compile-hibernate">
    <condition property="condition">
    <available file="**/*.hbm.xml" />
    </condition> 

<antcall target="condition-hibernate-part2"/>

</target>   

<target name="condition-hibernate-part2" description="check if there is a java and hbm file then call for compile-hibernate">
    <javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${hibernate.dir}">
</target>
```

I don't think that I can use Ant to solve my problem as I can't tell Ant what to compile and what not (I can using exclude and include) but I want to tell Ant compile only files that have an *.hbm.xml file next to them.

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase your question a little bit. Say, that you only want Java classes that have a corresponding .hbm.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to achieve this with Ant's built-in [selectors](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html).

However, if you cannot work around this in any other way you could implement a [custom selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/custom-programming.html#customselectors) that checks if the `.java` file has a corresponding `.hbm.xml` file, e.g.

```java
public class CorrespondingHbmSelector implements FileSelector {
  public boolean isSelected(File basedir, final String filename, File f) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.+).java$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(filename);
    boolean matches = m.matches();
    if (!matches) {
      return false;
    }
    final String basename = m.group(1);
    String[] foundFiles = basedir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
      @Override
      boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.startsWith(basename) && name.endsWith(".hbm.xml");
      }
    });
    return foundFiles.length > 0;
  }
}
```

Use it in your `build.xml` like an `include`

```xml
<typedef
  name="correspondinghbmselector"
  classname="CorrespondingHbmSelector"
  classpath="${mydomain.classes}"/>

<javac srcdir="${source.dir}" ...>
  <correspondinghbmselector/>
</javac>
```

This is just the basic idea. (I didn't test the code.)

The better way would be to avoid such complex dependencies in your build.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand from the question that he wants only those that have a corresponding `.hbm.xml` file. Makes sense, though.

Comment: I believe this would be the best solution, if I don't want to touch the code complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider separating the different types of classes into separate projects. Apart from making your packaging process simpler, there are other benefits too: decoupling, enforcing one-way compile-time dependencies etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Contact.java is not depending on AnotherClass.java, it is doable. Use [selector sub-elements](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html) (linked in the Ant documentation under "concepts and types") in your `javac` tag for this.

Here is an example:

```
    <javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${hibernate.dir}">
      <filename name="Contact.Java" />
    <javac>
```

Of course, instead of a `<filename>` selector you can also directly use the `patternset` subelements and attributes:

```
    <javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${hibernate.dir}">
      <include name="Contact.Java" />
    <javac>
```

or

```
    <javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${hibernate.dir}"
           includea="Contact.Java" />
```

By the way, the naming convention for Java's file extensions is using only lower case letters, i.e. `.java`, not `.Java` (and `.class`). If you are on a case-insensitive file system like most Windows file systems, this might not matter, but you should still do it, to avoid surprises later.)

Comment: I assumed that there is arbitrary number of .java files to compile that are not known at build time. Or, at least shahin wouldn't want to list all of them in the build file.

Comment: There would be more than one class like Contact.java. I am sorry if I didn't explain it thoroughly. So the only criteria to check would be a co-existing class with different extension but same fimename.

You are right about capital letters, that was my mistake typing the structure. It is lower case all the way.